# Django Postgresql Heroku : Operational Error - 'FATAL too many connections for role "usename"'

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am running a web application using Django and Django Rest Framework on Heroku with a postgresql and redis datastore. I am on the free postgresql tier which is limited to 20 connections.

This hasn't been an issue in the past, but recently I started using [django channels 2.](https://github.com/django/channels)0 and the [daphne server](https://github.com/django/daphne/) (switched my Procfile from gunicorn to daphne like [this tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django)) and now I have been running into all sort of weird problems.

The most critical is that connections to the database are being left open so as the app runs, the number of connections keep increasing until it reaches 20 and gives me the following error message: Operational Error - 'FATAL too many connections for role "usename"'

[image: Sentry Error Description]

[image: postgresql connection utilization]
Then I have to manually go to shell and type `heroku pg:killall` each time, this is obviously not a feasible solution and this is production so my users cant get access to site and get 500 errors.  Would really appreciate any help.

I have tried:

Adding this to my different views in different places

`from django.db import connections
conections.close_all()`

`for con in connections:
con.close()`

I also tried doing `SELECT * from pg_activity` and saw a bunch of stuff but have no idea what to make of it:

[image: Heroku Dataclip pg_activity]

Answer (score 6):

We figured out whats the problem. I assume that you are using dj_database_url like in heroku manual. All you have to do is to drop conn_max_age.

```
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
```

Answer (score 3):

### There is the solution:

Nowadays heroku provide the `django_heroku` package that deal with default django-heroku app configuration, so when you call `django_heroku.config(locals())` on the end of your settings.py the default `CONN_MAX_AGE` database config is set to `600` seconds, so the default of django is `0` what mean all database connections are been closed after request complete, if you don't replace the value of `CONN_MAX_AGE` after calling `django_heroku.config(locals())` the value of this field is default to `600` what mean the DB connections still alive for 600 seconds causing this trouble.

#### Put this line on the end of your settings.py, its mandatory to be after heroku config:

```
django_heroku.config(locals())
DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 0
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I still have to wait the default 600 seconds to pass before asking a new connection.

Comment: @RobZ Sure that you call the `DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 0` on the end of your settings.py and redeploy your app to heroku.

Comment: after more research what caused the trouble was some custom threads I was doing within a task/worker. Within the threads connections where maintained. Outside the threads ```DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = 0``` worked as expected and connections are immediately dropped after use.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved it.

One of the changes I made was modifying how I closed my connections.

The key is to close old connections before and after various view functions.

```
from django.db import close_old_connections

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET', ])
def search(request):
    close_old_connections()
    # do stuff
    close_old_connections()
```

Comment: You can use a tool like [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to see which views are holding the most SQL connections. Or you can try to deduce base on your understanding of how your app works, which of the views have the most database call.s